# Alamofire 4: Detecting No Network Connection

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I am able to find out if there's no network connection with Alamofire 3 since it enters the `guard` line if there's no WiFi.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
    .responseJSON { response in
        guard let object = response.result.value else {
            // no response <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            return
        }
        let json = JSON(object)
        ...
        ...
}
```

, where url is a string.  The following code is for Alamofire 4. Even when the application detects no network connection, it doesn't enter the `guard` line.

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
    guard let object = response.result.value else {
        // It doesn't enter here.
        return
    }
    let json = JSON(object)
    ...
    ...
}
```

I could use the `SystemConfiguration` framework to write a simple WiFi connection detection function.  But how could I let Alamofire 4 detects it?  I've read a few topics after running a search with [swift] [alamofire], by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire have reachability which can detect network condition, still, in your case, just simply check for `response.result.error` instead of checking for the result value, if there's no connection or any other error then it wont be nil

Comment: I'm afraid that won't help since response is empty where there's no connection with the configuration above.

Comment: I don't think response is ever empty once you called it, even if it have no connection, it will return an error, still, you might want to try reachability